# Shiny reactive outputs are not updating as expected

Tags: r, shiny

I have created a shiny app that pulls software components and their versions off of a list of nodes. The goal here is to make all of our nodes consistent when possible and this app helps us see which nodes are inconsistent.

Currently you can modify the version in the 'baseline' handsontable and it will reactively update the pivot table below with the change as well as the BaselineStats column within the handsontable. This works as expected. I have been asked to add the ability to upload a csv file that would overwrite the baseline table so a user does not have to change these 'baseline' versions each time they load the app.

In addition, there are some components that are 100% consistent. Currently those do not appear in the 'baseline' handsontable (since this is a tool to show inconsistency) but I have added a checkbox so that the user can still report on those components that are 100% consistent.

For some reason neither the fileUpload nor the checkboxInput are updating and no matter how much I poke and prod at my code, I cannot figure out why.

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(rpivotTable)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  # Create dataframe
df.consistency <- structure(list(Node = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
                                                                                    "D"), class = "factor"), Component = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                     4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("docker.version", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "kernel.version", "os.name", "os.version"), class = "factor"), 
                 Version = structure(c(10L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 10L, 
                                     5L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 9L), .Label = c("1.12.1", "1.13.1", 
                                                                              "16.04", "17.04", "18.04", "3.10.0", "3.11.0", "3.12.0", 
                                                                              "3.13.0", "RedHat"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                     -16L))

# Get Date Time
Report.Date <- Sys.Date()

df.baseline <- reactive({

  inputFile <- input$uploadBaselineData

  if(!is.null(inputFile)){

    read.csv(inputFile$datapath, header = input$header)

  } else{
    if(input$showConsistent == FALSE){

      # Count the number of occurrences for Version and Component, then remove the Components that are consistent (not duplicated => nn == 1) and then remove nn column
      df.clusterCons.countComponent <- df.consistency %>%
        add_count(Version, Component) %>%
        add_count(Component) %>%
        filter(nn > 1) %>%
        select(-nn)

      # Change back to dataframe after grouping
      df.clusterCons.countComponent <- as.data.frame(df.clusterCons.countComponent)

      # Components and Versions are shown for every node/cluster. 
      # Reduce this df to get only a unique Component:Version combinations
      df.clusterCons.dist_tbl <- df.clusterCons.countComponent %>%
        distinct(Component, Version, .keep_all = TRUE)

      #Create a df that contains only duplicated rows (rows that are unique i.e. versions are consistent, are removed)
      df.clusterCons.dist_tbl.dup <- df.clusterCons.dist_tbl %>%
        filter(Component %in% unique(.[["Component"]][duplicated(.[["Component"]])]))

      #Create a baseline df to be used to filter larger dataset later 
      #(baseline = max(n) for Version -- but must retain Component since that is the parameter we will use to filter on later)
      df.clusterCons.baseline <- df.clusterCons.dist_tbl.dup[order(df.clusterCons.dist_tbl.dup$Component, df.clusterCons.dist_tbl.dup$n, decreasing = TRUE),]
      df.clusterCons.baseline <- df.clusterCons.baseline[!duplicated(df.clusterCons.baseline$Component), ]
      df.clusterCons.baseline <- df.clusterCons.baseline %>% 
        select(Component, Version)



    }
    else{
      # Count the number of occurrences for Version and Component, then remove the Components that are consistent (not duplicated => nn == 1) and then remove nn column
      df.clusterCons.countComponent <- df.consistency %>%
        add_count(Version, Component) %>%
        add_count(Component) %>%
        select(-nn)

      # Change back to dataframe after grouping
      df.clusterCons.countComponent <- as.data.frame(df.clusterCons.countComponent)

      # Components and Versions are shown for every node/cluster. 
      # Reduce this df to get only a unique Component:Version combinations
      df.clusterCons.dist_tbl <- df.clusterCons.countComponent %>%
        distinct(Component, Version, .keep_all = TRUE)

      df.clusterCons.baseline <- df.clusterCons.dist_tbl[order(df.clusterCons.dist_tbl$Component, df.clusterCons.dist_tbl$n, decreasing = TRUE),]
      df.clusterCons.baseline <- df.clusterCons.baseline[!duplicated(df.clusterCons.baseline$Component), ]
      df.clusterCons.baseline <- df.clusterCons.baseline %>% 
        select(Component, Version)
    }
  }
})


df.componentVersionCounts <- df.consistency %>%
  add_count(Component) %>%
  rename("CountComponents" = n) %>%
  add_count(Component, Version) %>%
  rename("CountComponentVersions" = n) %>%
  mutate("BaselineStats" = paste0("Baseline: ", round(CountComponentVersions / CountComponents * 100, 2), "% of Total: ", CountComponents)) %>%
  select(Component, Version, BaselineStats) %>%
  distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)

df.componentVersions_tbl <- reactive({
  df.componentVersions_tbl <- df.baseline() %>%
    distinct(Component, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    select(Component, Version) %>%
    left_join(df.componentVersionCounts, by = c("Component" = "Component", "Version" = "Version"))

})

# Report Date Output
output$reportDate <- renderText({
  return(paste0("Report last run: ", Report.Date))
})

# handsontable showing baseline and allowing for an updated baseline
output$baseline_table <- rhandsontable::renderRHandsontable({

  rhandsontable(df.componentVersions_tbl(), rowHeaders = NULL) %>%
    hot_col("Component", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
    hot_col("BaselineStats", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
    hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE) %>%
    hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE, filters = TRUE)

})

observe({
  hot = isolate(input$baseline_table)
  if(!is.null(input$baseline_table)){
    handsontable <- hot_to_r(input$baseline_table)

    df.clusterCons.baseline2 <- handsontable %>%
      select(-BaselineStats)

    df.componentVersions_tbl <- df.clusterCons.baseline2  %>%
      left_join(df.componentVersionCounts, by = c("Component" = "Component", "Version" = "Version"))

    output$baseline_table <- rhandsontable::renderRHandsontable({

      rhandsontable(df.componentVersions_tbl, rowHeaders = NULL) %>%
        hot_col("Component", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
        hot_col("BaselineStats", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
        hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE) %>%
        hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE, filters = TRUE)

    })

    df.clusterIncons <- anti_join(df.consistency, handsontable, by = c("Component" = "Component", "Version" = "Version"))
    df.clusterIncons <- df.clusterIncons

    # Pivot Table showing data with inconsistencies 
    output$pivotTable <- rpivotTable::renderRpivotTable({
      rpivotTable::rpivotTable(df.clusterIncons, rows = c("Cluster", "Node"), cols = "Component", aggregatorName = "List Unique Values", vals = "Version", 
                               rendererName = "Table", 
                               inclusions = list(Component = list("os.version", "os.name", "kernel.version", "docker.version")))


    })

    output$downloadBaselineData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('baselineData-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
      },
      content = function(file) {
        baseline_handsontable <- handsontable %>%
          select(-BaselineStats)
        write.csv(baseline_handsontable, file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )


    output$downloadPivotData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('pivotData-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(df.clusterIncons, file, row.names = FALSE)
      }
    )

  }
})

})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)
library(rpivotTable)

dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Test Dashboard", titleWidth = "97%"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = TRUE,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("App", tabName = "app", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    tabItems(
      tabItem("app",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 3, background = "light-blue",
                    "This box includes details to the user about how the application works", br(), br(), br(), 
                    verbatimTextOutput("reportDate")
                ),
                box(width = 7, status = "info", title = "Version baselines based on greatest occurance",
                    rHandsontableOutput("baseline_table", height = "350px")
                ),
                column(width = 2, 
                       fluidRow(
                         fileInput("uploadBaselineData", "Upload Other Baseline Data:", multiple = FALSE, 
                                   accept = ".csv")
                       ),
                       fluidRow(
                         downloadButton("downloadBaselineData", "Download Baseline Data")
                       ),
                       br(), 
                       fluidRow(
                         downloadButton("downloadPivotData", "Download Pivot Table Data")
                       ),
                       br(), 
                       fluidRow(
                         checkboxInput("showConsistent", "Show Consistent Components in baseline")
                       )
                )
              ),
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12, status = "info", title = "Nodes with versions inconsistent with baseline",
                    div(style = 'overflow-x: scroll', rpivotTable::rpivotTableOutput("pivotTable", height = "500px"))
                )
              )
              )
    )
)
    )
```

I have worked with reactivity quite often but I do not frequently use observe or isolate so that may be where I am running into an issue. I did also try out the new reactlog package but I am still not sure of a path forward.

Here is a picture of the reactlog output before I click the check box or upload new baseline data:
[image: Reactlog Output 1] 
And after:
[image]

Comment: does `df<-read.csv(inputFile$datapath, header = input$header); return(df)` solve the csv issue?

Comment: @MaxwellChandler, nope. I tried that a couple days ago too :(

Comment: How about `inFile <- input$uploadBaselineData
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    return(df) if(` noticed I removed the else here

Comment: When the app first runs: no applicable method for 'distinct_' applied to an object of class "NULL". It does at least seem to respond to the csv input now though... Progress

Comment: I am getting this error: `could not find function "widgetFunc"`. I would also not include several render* funcions and downloadHandlers in an `observe()`, rather restructure your code, so that data is processed in `reactives` and then passed on to render* functions. This makes it hard to debug and might lead to weird behaviour.

Comment: @AlexDometrius Is `df.consistency` structure an example for us, or is it data you need to load every time? And why do you define it in that way?

Comment: @OmaymaS, yes that's just example data.

Comment: @AlexDometrius So if it for demo purposes, the CSV should have the same data, right?

Comment: @OmaymaS Yes. Though for my testing I changed a couple of the Versions around so I could tell if the data updates as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the given structure of the Shiny App is very tangled and it does not use reactivity efficiently. So first we can start with a simpler app to make sure the basic components are working, then add more.

**Some of the problems**

- the included dataframe `df.consistency` interferes with the real reactive components you want to add. For instance, the `if/else` flow is problematic because it always jumps to the first `else` since the csv does not exist when the app is launched and the expression to read it is not accurate, however `df.consistency` is always available.
- there is duplication of the same component like `output$baseline_table` which is defined twice.
- with `read.csv`, you passed an argument `header = input$header` which is not defined *(if you took this from the example [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/fileInput.html), it refers to the checkbox, but it is not valid here)*.

**Minimal app**

If you want to start with a minimal app, you can start with the following code. This will allow you to:

- use default data or upload a `csv` to override the default.
- view the results in the `rhandsontable` in the middle.

Notice that:

- `baseline_data` is reactive, that's why the other expressions that use it are also reactive.
- if you want to have different calculations of `df.componentVersionCounts` depending on the checkbox, you can add the `if/else` inside the expression to write the calculations for both cases.

```
library(shiny)
library(rpivotTable)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)

## UI ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- dashboardPage(

  dashboardHeader(title = "Test Dashboard", titleWidth = "97%"),

  dashboardSidebar(
    collapsed = TRUE,
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("App", tabName = "app", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(

    tabItems(
      tabItem("app",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 3, background = "light-blue",
                    "This box includes details to the user about how the application works", br(), br(), br(), 
                    verbatimTextOutput("reportDate")
                ),
                box(width = 7, status = "info", title = "Version baselines based on greatest occurance",
                    rHandsontableOutput("baseline_table", height = "350px")
                ),

                column(width = 2, 
                       fluidRow(
                         fileInput("uploadBaselineData", "Upload Other Baseline Data:", multiple = FALSE, 
                                   accept = ".csv")
                       ),

                       fluidRow(
                         checkboxInput("showConsistent", "Show Consistent Components in baseline")
                       )
                )
              )
      )
    )
  )
)


## define default baseline data
df.consistency <- structure(list(Node = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L),
                                                  .Label = c("A", "B", "C", 
                                                                                                    "D"), class = "factor"), Component = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                     4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("docker.version", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                             "kernel.version", "os.name", "os.version"), class = "factor"), 
                                 Version = structure(c(10L, 3L, 1L, 6L, 10L, 3L, 1L, 7L, 10L, 
                                                       5L, 1L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 9L),
                                                     .Label = c("1.12.1", "1.13.1", 
                                                                                                "16.04", "17.04", "18.04", "3.10.0", "3.11.0", "3.12.0", 
                                                                                                "3.13.0", "RedHat"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                             -16L))


## Server ------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {

  ## Get Date Time
  Report.Date <- Sys.Date()

  baseline_data <- reactive({

    inputFile <- input$uploadBaselineData
    if(!is.null(inputFile)){
      ## WHEN A CSV IS UPLOADED
      read.csv(inputFile$datapath)
    }else{
      ## DEFAULT
      df.consistency #or write the any other expression to read from a certain path or query
    }
  })

  ## df.componentVersionCounts ---------------------------------------------------------------
  df.componentVersionCounts <- reactive({
    req(baseline_data())

    baseline_data() %>%
      add_count(Component) %>%
      rename("CountComponents" = n) %>%
      add_count(Component, Version) %>%
      rename("CountComponentVersions" = n) %>%
      mutate("BaselineStats" = paste0("Baseline: ", round(CountComponentVersions / CountComponents * 100, 2), "% of Total: ", CountComponents)) %>%
      select(Component, Version, BaselineStats) %>%
      distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
  })

  ## df.componentVersions_tbl ------------------------------------------------------------ 
  df.componentVersions_tbl <- reactive({
    req(baseline_data())

    baseline_data() %>% ##df.baseline()
      distinct(Component, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
      select(Component, Version) %>%
      left_join(df.componentVersionCounts(),
                by = c("Component" = "Component", "Version" = "Version"))

  })

  # handsontable showing baseline and allowing for an updated baseline ---------------------
  output$baseline_table <- rhandsontable::renderRHandsontable({

    rhandsontable(df.componentVersions_tbl(), rowHeaders = NULL) %>%
      hot_col("Component", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
      hot_col("BaselineStats", readOnly = TRUE) %>%
      hot_cols(columnSorting = TRUE) %>%
      hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE, filters = TRUE)

  })

  # Report Date Output -------------------------------------------------------
  output$reportDate <- renderText({
    return(paste0("Report last run: ", Report.Date))
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I think we were talking past each other in the comments above. I do not simply want the user to upload their own data as a baseline. The data that is read in when the app loads should be the default. The user can then override that baseline data if they choose by uploading a csv file.